# Which plant produces the most oxygen?

Tags: oxygen, plant

Which plant is the most efficient in making oxygen for it's weight? I want to think it is the greenest plant with more leaves and least                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  trunk in full sun?

Comment: Some quick research suggest that the answer very much depends on environmental factors such as amount of sunlight received and growth cycle. For example, over the course of a year, some trees go from bare branches to fully leaved; they're not producing at all for part of the year. Whereas algae rapidly multiply in the proper circumstances and die when they're not productive. (This UC Santa Barbara post suggests that the answer isn't known: http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=832) Which is to say, your answer might depend on providing a specific context.

Comment: Do you consider algae as plants?

Comment: @Michael it may be the ideal plant

Comment: Algae and other unicelulars should be more efficinet doing that task. Talking about plants, I can not affirm it but at a web of gardener they say Spathiphyllum. https://www.jardineriaon.com/spathiphyllum-la-planta-que-mas-oxigena-los-ambientes.html wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spathiphyllum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read an article saying that algae produces more oxygen than all the plants in the world!!
Edit: https://www.nps.gov/romo/learn/nature/algae.htm       First paragraph last lines

Comment: You need to link the article then so others can read into it more and adjudicate whether it's a reasonable source rather than just taking your word for it!

Comment: Ill try to find it and link it. Thanks for the heads-up